# line is not visiable in HighChart

Tags: jquery, csv, highcharts

I have a trouble with loading CSV to highcharts. I do not know why that line is not visible in linechart. this is code which should show me chart on webpage:

```js
var Categories = [];
var Data = [];
var Mychart;
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var options={
    chart:{
     renderTo:'chart',
     
    },
    title:{
     text:'Data Test'
    },
    xAxis:{
     categories:[]
    },
    yAxis:{
     title:{
      text:'Time'
     }
    },
    series:[]
  
  };
  
  $.get('File/test5.csv',function(data){
   var lines = data.split('\n');
   $.each(lines,function(lineNo,line){
    var items = line.split(',');
    Categories.push(items[0]);
    Data.push(parseInt(items[1]));
   });
   options.xAxis.categories = Categories;
   options.series = [{data:Data},{type:'spline'}];
   Mychart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

please help me!!!

Comment: Can you post an example of the data in `File/test5.csv`? Also, try `console.log('Categories', Categories); console.log('Data', Data);` just before the `new Highcharts...` line and check your console

Comment: this is File/test5.csv : 2013-01-01 12:00,380.8
2013-01-02 12:01,383.4
2013-01-03 12:02,383.1
2013-01-04 12:03,382.4
2013-01-05 12:04,379.8
2013-01-06 12:05,377.9
2013-01-07 12:06,376.8
2013-01-08 12:07,377.3
2013-01-09 12:08,377
2013-01-10 12:09,378.4                                                                                                                     and I tried your way. but I don't know your way. Tell me more to me please.

Comment: How your "Data" looks like, after parsing

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have the `series` option wrong. Where you have

```
options.series = [{data:Data},{type:'spline'}];
```

it should probably be

```
options.series = [{data: Data, type: 'spline'}];
```

Note that there's only one array entry in my example.

Comment: thank you tell me how!!!!. I became to be able to see the graph. but I was seen in terms of data in the graph. Line did not come out.